# Webpack - Expose `window` as `global`

Tags: webpack

I'm using the [asap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asap) package with Webpack. [The package uses `global`.](https://github.com/kriskowal/asap/blob/master/browser-raw.js#L81) How can I expose `window` as `global` with webpack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out the [imports-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imports-loader). It would work out like this:

```
require('imports-loader?global=window!asap');
```