# Is there a way to get momentJS from window?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way to get an instance of momentJS from `window`? Or, is there a familiar name which momentJS is defined?

Note: I've been using momentJS within a package bundler (Webpack).

I need to eval() a text and on its current implementation I need to use an instance of momentJS.

Something like:

```
eval('moment(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), 9, 0))');
```

The problem is that `moment` isn't defined inside this context.

Comment: Cloudflare hosts most JS libraries to be consumed on the client. Here's moment (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/). Grab the latest or which ever version you want

Comment: I've been using momentJS as package and transpiling to get it using Webpack, however, I'd like to check how to get it from the `window` for a specific purpose.

Comment: I think i don't understand the question. You can get it using `moment` key: `window.moment` or just `moment`

Comment: @lucifer63 I've been using momentJS within a package bundler (webpack), so, it isn't available in the way you've described above.

Comment: What does `window.moment` give you?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin `undefined` even having it instantiated and been used in other cases - using `import moment from 'moment'`

Comment: Hey, it's completely ok. Just bind your `moment` to `window.moment`

Comment: Or use `global.moment = moment` and [expose global as window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785715/webpack-expose-window-as-global) so it also works with node server and client side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From docs: `the globally exported moment object was deprecated`

Therefore you'll have to bind it manually:

```
import moment from 'moment';

window.moment = moment;
```